# Why is it important to keep away from the doctrines of absolute self and absolute non-self?

Tags: anatman

There are two doctrines. Existence of self and existence of no self. Existence of self means eternalism. Existence of no self means nihilism.
If self is eternal then there is no escape from suffering. If there is no self then there is no meaning of good deeds and bad deeds.

There is a middle path.

Depending upon ignorance , volitional formations arise,depending upon volitional formations ,consciousness arise , depending upon consciousness , name and form arise, depending upon name and form, six senses arise, depending on six senses , contact arises, depending upon contact , feelings arise, depending upon feelings , clinging arise, depending upon clinging, cravings arise, depending upon cravings,attachments arise, depending upon attachments , becoming arise , depending upon becoming , birth, ageing , death and whole mass of suffering arises.

My question is: Why is it important to keep away from the doctrines of absolute self and absolute non-self?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question does not appear to be about Buddhist philosophy, teaching, and practice

Answer (score 1):

Eternalism = permanence of a self

Annihilationism = a temporary self bound for eventual annihilation.

Anatta = absence of any real self anywhere = absolute not-self

Answer (score 0):

WHY

It is important to keep away from the doctrines of absolute self and absolute non-self for the following reason- as doctrines arising from ignorance (cognitive ignorance in this case; ignorance about the truth of reality of phenomena [also called as soteriological truth of highest meaning]) they lead to more craving and aversion being created/produced and thus continuity in the wheel of life.

HOW

To abandon the doctrines of absolute self and absolute non-self, one has to remove the cognitive ignorance- which can be done with reasoning on emptiness. To see that the labels self and non-self have only conventional reality steers one away from creating more karma and continued rebirth.

SUMMARY

Doing so, is to see phenomena as arising based on causes and conditions- which is the opposite of 'absolute'. Absolute being does not need any other thing but according to Buddha, all phenomena have the character of dependent origination.